# Word VBA For Changing Text Format

Tags: colors, ms-word, properties, case

**EDITED w/code I found to work ——**
It's been a while since I've done any real intensive coding in Word VBA (2008 thereabouts) so either it's changed A LOT or my memory has. I convert client books from digital to print and I need to ensure everything in italics transfers into print. I've tried styles for this, but they're conflicting with each other as I use different styles for different genres. So I built a macro to convert all italics in the digital book to all caps that I can alter in the print format.

When I change italics to All Caps in the digital document, I can then change to the print style template, clear all formatting to a basic text and the caps remain. Italics disappear if I do that. I then created another macro to find all caps and highlight wdpink. My second macro then removes the highlight and changes the caps to lowercase and italics, but I want to converting to red font in the same macro. If I remove the code font color to red the macro below works, but I then have to do a search and replace italics to red, as I use the red to find words to be capitalized at the beginning of a sentence or is a proper noun. IT works, but why not accomplish the task all in one swoop. It's more efficient. I've tried to do if/else statement after a find all caps using A-Z code with 2 (and 1) to avoid doing the highlights. I've tried Active document code, etc. but I can't get any of it made the bloody text red or any color. If I could resolve the color code line, I'd be jubilant. TIA Monica

```
        
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    While Selection.Find.Found
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    Selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
     ' Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdClassicRed
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Wend

End Subd
```

EDITED I found a workaround. It doesn't hold all the changes I want in the same macro, so I have to run it in three different macros for the three criteria as I've not had time to figure out how to combine it all together other than doing a call macro. But color me happy and relieved I don't have to fight with 10+ style sheets that don't like being interfered with since authors send me their docs formatted with their own style sheets, and they don't like to change those style sheets.
++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Sub Ca1S_R1()
  Dim objRange As Range

 
  With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
 
    With Selection.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "[A-Z]{2,}"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      Set objRange = Selection.Range
        objRange.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
         Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
        

      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If at all possible, you should be defining one or more styles and applying those rather than direct formatting. This results in easier to edit files that are smaller and less complex.

Comment: I second Charles' comment. Replace the italics with an italic style and avoid all the caps/colored text manipulations.

Comment: As I stated, converting a file from a digital style sheet to print style sheet creates major formatting conflicts. W/print every font in the style sheet has to be embedded in the printer's PDF, which creates conflicts So I can't include digital fonts. The only option I've found to keep italics when changing style sheets is to set all italics in caps BEFORE I apply the print styles. I then have to strip the digital style out of the doc so the print styles can take over with out font conflicts. When I strip it doesn't keep italics, but it will CAPS. Hence the need for a macro.

Comment: I also tried creating the same style of italics and caps and colored text before I messed with a macro. I placed the style in BOTH the digital and print styles sheets. It still carried over some of the digital font/formats to print and I wound up cleaning up a lot more issues than I do if I just use the caps. I've been using Word and Styles for years.  I work with authors of contemp romance, historical romance, women's fiction, sci-fi. EVERY one of those genres has a different style sheet. It's not quite a simple as it sounds

Comment: I found a macro that does what I need.

Comment: This is a user-to-user support forum. Mind sharing what you found?

Comment: Sorry, should have done that last night.