# Copy conditional formatting from Excel to Word table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have written VBA code to copy the values from an Excel workbook into a Word table that is located in our report template.

I conditionally formatted (after the fact) the Excel cells that if the value is greater than 0 then a green arrow shows, if the value is less than 0 then a red arrow shows and if it is 0 a yellow zero shows.

My copy paste VBA code that takes the value from a cell in Excel and pastes into a coded template in Word:

```vb
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<change2>>"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection = Sheet8.Cells(14, 9).Text
.Application.Selection.EndOf
```

The <> represents the value difference between this audit and last audit but I now have to copy and paste special for not just the text to show up but also the arrows.

I tried `pastespecial.text`.

Comment: Copying and pasting can not transfer Excel's conditional formatting to Word.

Comment: You will need to explicitly code the format in Word like this  ...    `.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed` the ColorIndex in Excel would be something like xlRed. See this link  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876563/word-vba-for-changing-text-format

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, copying the individual arrows from cells with conditional formatting is not directly possible. The arrows are part of the cell’s formatting, not individual objects that can be copied separately.

However, you can copy the entire cell (including its formatting) to another cell. Here’s an example of how you can do this using VBA:

```
Sub CopyFormat()
Range("A1").Copy
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Comment: OP is looking for copying cells with condtional formatting from Excel to Word.